# Get Line Breaks From string in c#?

Tags: html, string, c#-4.0

I have simple text which have line

```
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
```

thing i want to do is that when line breaks i want to insert `<br />` pragmatically in c# . Can i ?

Comment: Insert what? Before? After? What has the HTML tag got to do with this?

Comment: i want to insert "<br />" at every line break

Answer (score 7):

Something like this ?

```
   string TheText= "BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH\nBLAH BLAH BLAH\nFOOOOOOOOO";  
   string replaced = TheText.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>")
                    .Replace("\r", "<br/>")
                    .Replace("\n", "<br/>");
```

Answer (score 4):

How about a simple string replacement ...

```
string.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br/>");
```

(You may have to determine the exact type of line-break used in your input string though)

Comment: Aaahhhh ... oh no ... it's a snake!

Comment: If everyone was using `System.Environment.NewLine`, the world would be a better place!